# Why is the function running before AsyncStorage is finished

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, asyncstorage

I'm here with an issue regarding react native, I started a project about 2 weeks ago and its the first time I'm trying this framework and never worked with JavaScript ever so it's being hard...

What I would like to know is why my function called 'check_Authentication' which just checks if the variables of a .js file called 'Globals" that have the default values presented runs before I can finish my AsyncStorage tasks to assign it new ones

Here is my code
this two function as you can see are AsyncStorage and after I either get an item or set one...I call a function called 'Update_Globals' that is in another .js file and update my global variables from my other .js file called 'Globals' so that I can use them later on.

```
async function set_Async(field, value){
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(field, value);
        await update_Globals(field,value);
    } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('something wrong with setting async storage');
    }
}

async function get_Async(field){
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(field);
        await update_Globals(field,value);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('something wrong with getting async storage');
    }
}
```

Here is the .js file with the function to update my global variables mentioned above

```
import globals from './globals.js';

export function update_Globals(field,value){
    alert("Updating field: " + field + " with value: " + value);
    switch(field) {
        case globals.is_logged_in_name:

            globals.is_logged_in_value = value;
            break;
        case globals.account_status_name:
            globals.account_status_value = value;
            break;
        case globals.account_role_name:
            globals.account_role_value = value;
            break;
        case globals.account_user_name:
            globals.account_user_value = value;
            break;
        case globals.account_api_token_name:
            globals.account_api_token_value = value;
            break;
        case globals.account_profile_status_name:
            globals.account_profile_status_value = value;
            break;
        default:
            alert("No variable found")
    }
}
```

and here is the .js file with the variables

```
module.exports = {
    is_logged_in_name: 'is_logged_in',
    is_logged_in_value: 'false',

    account_status_name: 'account_status',
    account_status_value: '0',

    account_role_name: 'account_role',
    account_role_value: '0',

    account_user_name: 'account_user',
    account_user_value: '0',

    account_api_token_name: 'account_api_token',
    account_api_token_value: '0',

    account_profile_status_name: 'account_profile_status',
    account_profile_status_value: 'empty',

    testing_name: "name",
    testing_value: "Chrystello",
};
```

and this function is where it all goes together

```
async function do_Login(){
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
            firebase_token: firebase_token,
        })
    })
        .then(function(responseData) {
            if(responseData.ok){
                return responseData.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');

        })
        .then(function(responseData) {
            const response = responseData["response"];
            const response_array = response[0];

        set_Async(globals.account_user_name,
replace_Quote_Marks(JSON.stringify(response_array["user_id"]))).done();
        set_Async(globals.account_status_name,
replace_Quote_Marks(JSON.stringify(response_array["status_id"]))).done();
        set_Async(globals.account_profile_status_name,
replace_Quote_Marks(JSON.stringify(responseData["status"]))).done();
        set_Async(globals.account_role_name,
replace_Quote_Marks(JSON.stringify(response_array["role_id"]))).done();     
        set_Async(globals.account_api_token_name,
replace_Quote_Marks(JSON.stringify(response_array["api_token"]))).done();
        })
        .then(function () {
            try{
                check_Authentication()
            }catch(error){
                throw new Error("couln't run function");
            }

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

in here you can see me calling the set_Async() function where I send the name and value I want to store and after it is supposed to update my .js file with the new values and after the 5 are done I then proceed to checking each value to then decide whether the user can or can't log in but it always return the default number the first time I click the button, the second time works because he has the new values so I can only assume that the function check_Authenticantion is running before the AsyncStorages

the function check_aunthentication is this one

```
function check_Authentication() {
Alert.alert("I Got user " + globals.account_user_value)
if(globals.account_user_value != "0"){
    const account_status = check_Account_Status(globals.account_status_value)
    return_value = JSON.stringify(account_status["return_value"])
    if(return_value == "true"){
        screen = JSON.stringify(account_status["screen"]);
        if(screen == "ForcePassword"){
            return true;
        }
        const account_profile = check_Account_Profile(globals.account_profile_status_value)
        return_value = JSON.stringify(account_profile["return_value"])
        if(return_value == "true"){
            screen = JSON.stringify(account_profile["screen"])
            const account_role = check_Account_Role(globals.account_role_value)
            return_value = JSON.stringify(account_role["return_value"])
            if(return_value == "true"){
                screen = JSON.stringify(account_role["screen"]) + screen
                screen = replace_Quote_Marks(screen)
                return true;
            }else{
                message = JSON.stringify(account_profile["message"])
                Alert.alert(message)
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            message = JSON.stringify(account_profile["message"])
            Alert.alert(message)
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        message = JSON.stringify(account_status["message"])
        Alert.alert(message)
        return false;
    }
}else{
    Alert.alert("No User Found")
    return false;
}
}
```

and this is how I run the main function to trigger all the events

```
<TouchableHighlight
    style = {styles.submit_button}
    onPress={() => {
        do_Login().done()
    }
    }>
    <Text style = {styles.submit_text}>Login</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions like that.

Comment: You can replace your entire setter function with `obj[name] = value`.

Comment: There is no point in having separate variables that hold names of other variables.

Comment: Your code isn't actually async, and when it is, you aren't actually awaiting it.  Don't use `await` and `then()` together.

Comment: *replace entire setter function*
how exactly can i achieve that can you give an example?

Comment: You shouldn't have that setter function in the first place.  You should simply set properties directly.

Comment: i have that to store the values so when the user shutdown the application but didnt log out..it logs in automatically..atleast thats the way i want it to be 
like i said im still new to this

Comment: Your function is no different from `globals.foo = bar`.

Comment: but is that the issue that is causing the function to run before its finishe's setting the new values?

Answer (score -1):

i have found a work arround, might not be the best option but id did the trick..

Removing the `await` from the `AsyncStorage` functions somehow made the `check_Authentication` wait for `AsyncStorage` to finish setting the values

thanks @SLaks for your time